# How do you add buoyancy to a Webots robot without custom physics?

Tags: webots

For instance, can I simulate underwater vehicles or helium blimps?

I know about the sample blimp world in `projects/robots/epfl/lis/worlds/blimp.wbt` but this uses a custom physics plugin that appears to support exactly **one** blimp (it's hardcoded to look for the `blimp_lis` robot), whereas I want a lot of blimps.

Also `blimp.wbt` seems overcomplicated for my use case, if I could just set one of the `Solids` of my robot body to be positively buoyant or have negative mass that would get the job done.

I see the menu item View -> Optional Rendering -> Show Center of Buoyancy which leads me to believe this is possible somehow.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to add buoyancy in Webots without a physics plug-in. A simple example is provided in `WEBOTS_HOME/projects/samples/geometries/worlds/floating_geometries.wbt`. A more complicated example with water buoyancy is provided in `WEBOTS_HOME/projects/robots/epfl/biorob/worlds/salamander.wbt` where a salamander robot is swimming in a water pool. Finally, a air buoyancy example is provided in `WEBOTS_HOME/projects/robots/dji/mavic/worlds/mavic_2_pro.wbt`. Unlike the blimp you mentioned, none of these examples use a physics plug-in.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out from the example worlds, this is how to do it:

1. Add a top-level [Fluid](https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/fluid) node
2. Set its `boundingObject` field to something that covers the whole space, like a big `Box`.
3. Give the Fluid a name. E.g. I named mine **air**.

Then for each object you want to make buoyant:

1. Give it an `immersionProperties` field with the `fluidName` set to **air**
2. Be sure to set its `boundingObject` field otherwise Webots can't compute how it is immersed in the fluid.
3. Add a `Physics` node and play with the density or mass to get the buoyancy you want.